# How to index PDF content in Sitecore running on Azure Web App?

Tags: media-library, azure-search

I am trying to index media content (such as PDFs) using Azure and to my surprise/frustration, this feature isn't supported: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/830385

Is there a workaround that allows me to index file content on Azure?

Comment: I've done an implementation that should solve the problem - it can be found here https://github.com/michaelthyregod/Contrib.Sitecore.ContentSearch/tree/master/src/Contrib.Sitecore.ContentSearch.TikaOnDotnet - thee is also some nuget packages available - but currently only for 8.2 versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current implementation of `Sitecore.ContentSearch` API depends on Adobe IFilter v9, which can't be installed in [Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/).

At the same time, [Azure Search](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/search/) itself supports indexing different document formats (PDFs, DOCX/DOC, XLSX/XLS, PPTX/PPT, MSG etc.) when using Azure Blob Storage + Indexer for it: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage

Unfortunately, Sitecore doesn't support Azure Blob Storage for Media Library. It keeps blobs in `Master` and `Web` databases in SQL Server.

However, you can override the default `MediaItemContentExtractor`, and replace dependency on Adobe iFilter COM component, with [.NET port](https://github.com/KevM/tikaondotnet) of [Apache Tiki](https://tika.apache.org/).

See the `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config` file

```
<fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
... 
  <field type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.MediaItemContentExtractor,Sitecore.ContentSearch" fieldName="_content">
    <mediaIndexing ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration/mediaIndexing"/>
  </field>
...
</fields>
```

Comment: I've ran into an issue with this where it seems it only works with small PDF files. When using a larger files (such as 1MB) the item doesn't get indexed. The computed field gets hit, and returns the content, but the item just doesn't get updated in the index & there is nothing in the logs to suggest an error. The only limitation I can see documented on Azure Search is that documents cannot be greater than 16MB - no field level restrictions. So this doesn't seem like a viable solution at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own computed field that uses a PDF library to parse the file contents and store it in the index.

I followed this example: https://jeffdarchuk.com/2017/02/12/search-pdf-content-in-sitecore/

```
public class IndexPdfContent : IComputedIndexField
{
    public object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
    {
        try
        {
            var sitecoreIndexable = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;

            if (sitecoreIndexable == null) return null;

            var pdfContent = new SitecorePdfParser(new MediaItem(sitecoreIndexable)).ExtractText().ToList();

            if (pdfContent.Count == 0) return null;

            return string.Join(" ", pdfContent);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error("Unable to assemble PDF content for the search index ", e, this);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The main drawback is that this only includes PDF files. Sitecore on Lucene supports many different file types such as word documents etc, so that is something to consider.